# Dynamic Web Project HTTP ERROR:503

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, servlets

I am making a dynamic web project with mysql database connectivity in eclipse using dynamic web module 3.0,jdk 1.7
This is my project structure
[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZZUg.png)

web.xml for it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Project</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>AdminLogin</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.servlets.AdminLogin</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>AddBook</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.servlets.AddBook</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>AddBookForm</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.servlets.AddBookForm</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>AddLibrarian</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.servlets.AddLibrarian</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>AddLibrarianForm</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.servlets.AddLibrarianForm</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>DeleteBook</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.servlets.DeleteBook</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>DeleteLibrarian</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.servlets.DeleteLibrarian</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>EditLibrarian</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.servlets.EditLibrarian</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>IssueBook</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.servlets.IssueBook</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>IssueBookForm</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.servlets.IssueBookForm</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>LibrarianLogin</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.servlets.LibrarianLogin</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>LogoutAdmin</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.servlets.LogoutAdmin</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>LogoutLibrarian</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.servlets.LogoutLibrarian</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>ReturnBook</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.servlets.ReturnBook</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>ViewBook</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.servlets.ViewBook</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>ViewIssuedBook</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.servlets.ViewIssuedBook</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>ViewLibrarian</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.servlets.ViewLibrarian</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>AdminLogin</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/AdminLogin</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>AddBook</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/AddBook</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>AddBookForm</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/AddBookForm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>AddLibrarian</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/AddLibrarian</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>AddLibrarianForm</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/AddLibrarianForm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>DeleteBook</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/DeleteBook</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>DeleteLibrarian</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/DeleteLibrarian</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>EditLibrarian</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/EditLibrarian</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>EditLibrarianForm</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/EditLibrarianForm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>IssueBook</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/IssueBook</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>IssueBookForm</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/IssueBookForm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>LibrarianLogin</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/LibrarianLogin</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>LogoutAdmin</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/LogoutAdmin</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>LogoutLibrarian</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/LogoutLibrarian</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ReturnBook</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/ReturnBook</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ReturnBookForm</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/ReturnBookForm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ViewBook</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/ViewBook</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ViewIssuedBook</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/ViewIssuedBook</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ViewLibrarian</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/ViewLibrarian</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I have included mysql-connector.jar in java resources/lib only.

When i am running it it shows

```
HTTP ERROR: 503

Problem accessing /Project/AdminLogin. Reason: 
    Service Unavailable


Powered by Jetty://
```

But when I am using the web.xml as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Project</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>AdminLogin</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.servlets.AdminLogin</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>AdminLogin</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/AdminLogin</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

it opens the AdminLogin page but after that when I open other servlets it shows error as

```
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /Project/AddLibrarianForm. Reason: 
    Not Found
```

Is the problem due to my web.xml file or something else?

Comment: Is all servlet class created?

Comment: @ Sanjay Patel ,yes all servlets classes are created